# jQuery, ordering rows in a table using numbers in child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sort the rows in a table using the number in an anchor (anchor that not exist in some rows). Table example:

```
<table id="sortedtable" class="full">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Main tr</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">Title</div>
                <a class="unreadcount" href="#">7</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">No anchor here :(</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">Javascripthatesme</div>
                <a class="unreadcount" href="#">15</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">Yourox</div>
                <a class="unreadcount" href="#">2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">This has more than one word and no anchor</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">Title</div>
                <a class="unreadcount" href="#">11</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="float: left;">Big Bang Theory is not funny</div>
                <a class="unreadcount" href="#">4</a>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Using the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156851/using-jquery-how-do-you-reorder-rows-in-a-table-based-on-a-tr-attribute) I was able to make a semi-working code:

```
var $table = $('table');

var rows = $table.find('tr').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).find('a.unreadcount').text();
    var keyB = $(b).find('a.unreadcount').text();
    if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

You can see it working in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLvwz/1/). The problem and where I need help is the way numbers are sorted (8 come first than 32 or 12, for example) and that I need to ignore the first row (where "Main tr" is) and leave it always at the top.

And as an extra, if you could give me the direction to make a button that put the table in the original order again would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the text values to numbers for a proper numeric sort. The easies way to convert is with the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29).

To leave the heading row in place just don't include that in the array you sort, which is easy enough using jQuery's [`.slice()` method](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

To add a button that restores the table to its original order just keep a copy of the array before you sort it, which I've done with the standard [Array `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

So:

```
var $table = $('table');

var originalRows = $table.find('tr').slice(1).get(),
    rows = originalRows.slice(0);
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = +$(a).find('a.unreadcount').text();
    var keyB = +$(b).find('a.unreadcount').text();
    if (keyA < keyB) return 1;
    if (keyA > keyB) return -1;
    return 0;
});
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $table.children('tbody').append(row);
});

// button that changes it back:
$("input").click(function(){
    $.each(originalRows, function(index, row) {
       $table.children('tbody').append(row);
    });
});
​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hLvwz/5/