# jQuery Sort Table Rows Based on Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a table that I would like to sort based on the value of a hidden input in each row. The inputs will always be numeric and in the third column. I would like to sort in descending order. Here's a sample of the table. Thanks!

```
<table class="sortMe">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-cat">Category</th>
        <th class="col-title">Title</th>
        <th class="col-id"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-cat">Article Category</td>
        <td class="col-title">Article Title 1</td>
        <td class="col-id">
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1250">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-cat">Article Category</td>
        <td class="col-title">Article Title 2</td>
        <td class="col-id">
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="426">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-cat">Article Category</td>
        <td class="col-title">Article Title 2</td>
        <td class="col-id">
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="35621">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There's a good answer here which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3156974/5009210 . If you're still stuck, come back and I'll help you adapt it for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link @DuncanThacker. I should have mentioned I tried similar code before and can sort the table by the text of a cell and just tried the attribute like your link and it worked. Something about getting the input value is throwing me off.