# How to insert <tr>'s at certain position in html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed a table with headers. I am appending dynamic rows `<tr>` to this table. While appending I am losing the order of the rows. Any suggestion or ideas as to how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr>
            <th>Name</span></th>
            <th>Description</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    -- dynamic rows will come.
</table>

var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>'; // This position is fine
var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>'; // This one is having id '3', it should go to 3rd position. when 2nd comes.
var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>'; // This should go to 2nd position.

$('#myTable').append(html1);
$('#myTable').append(html2);
$('#myTable').append(html3);
```

Desired Output :

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr>
            <th>Name</span></th>
            <th>Description</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr id="1">
         <td>aaa</td>
         <td>aaa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
         <td>ccc</td>
         <td>ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
         <td>bbb</td>
         <td>bbb</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: for that you should loop the count and than based on value or priority generate html simple. You do not generate and append html as you done, but add logic for this

Comment: how you generate html1, html2 html3, write the condition in your question

Comment: @Craicerjack Yes sorry for that, I updated the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This you will do. Add a sorting function and then call that function as described in below link.

Added snippet based on Jquery content sorting link:- https://www.shift8web.ca/2017/01/use-jquery-sort-reorganize-content/

```js
var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>'; // This position is fine
var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>'; // This one is having id '3', it should go to 3rd position. when 2nd comes.
var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>'; // This should go to 2nd position.

$('#myTable').append(html1);
$('#myTable').append(html2);
$('#myTable').append(html3);

var i;
var htmlcontent = $('#myTable').html();
 $('#myTableOriginalContent ').html( $('#myTable').html())
sortMeBy('id', 'myTable', 'tr', 'asc')
function sortMeBy(arg, sel, elem, order) {
        var $selector = $('#'+sel),
        $element = $selector.children(elem);           
        $element.sort(function(a, b) {
                var an = parseInt(a.getAttribute(arg)),
                bn = parseInt(b.getAttribute(arg));
                if (order == "asc") {
                        if (an > bn)
                        return 1;
                        if (an < bn)
                        return -1;
                } else if (order == "desc") {
                        if (an < bn)
                        return 1;
                        if (an > bn)
                        return -1;
                }
                return 0;
        });
        $element.detach().appendTo($selector);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original Content
<table id="myTableOriginalContent">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Name</span></th>
            <th><span>Description</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
</table>

Desired Result
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <th><span>Name</span></th>
            <th><span>Description</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$('#myTable').append(html3);` to `$(html3).insertAfter('#1')`. Also note that you'll need a `tbody` element after the `thead` to contain your rows, but I would imagine the browser will be inserting one for you automatically. Try this:

```js
var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>';
var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>';
var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>';

$('#myTable tbody').append(html1).append(html2);

$(html3).insertAfter('#1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but he wants `bbb` in his second row. He's made a mistake in his `var`s

Comment: No, not at all. Look at the comments and output in the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is you append all dynamic table rows then reorder them based on the attribute of the id.

Sorting code source: [Using jquery, how do you reorder rows in a table based on a TR attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156851/using-jquery-how-do-you-reorder-rows-in-a-table-based-on-a-tr-attribute)

I just modified it a little.

```js
var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>'; // This position is fine
var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>'; // This one is having id '3', it should go to 3rd position. when 2nd comes.
var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>'; // This should go to 2nd position.

var html4 = '<tr id="5"><td>5th</td><td>5th</td></tr>'; // This should go to 5th position.

var html5 = '<tr id="4"><td>4th</td><td>4th</td></tr>'; // This should go to 4th position.

$('#myTable tbody').append(html1);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html2);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html3);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html4);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html5);


var $table=$('#myTable');

var rows = $table.find('tr').get();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
var keyA = $(a).attr('id');
var keyB = $(b).attr('id');
if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
return 0;
});
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
$table.children('tbody').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr>
            <th>Name</span></th>
            <th>Description</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple just you are calling wrong way call this way

```
$('#myTable').append(html1);
$('#myTable').append(html3);
$('#myTable').append(html2);
```

Complete Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

 <table id="myTable">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</span></th>
        <th>Description</span>
        </th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 </table>

 </body>
 </html>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $( document ).ready(function() {

 var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>';
 var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>'; 
 var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>'; 
 $('#myTable thead').after(html1,html3,html2);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try Following**

Add `<tbody>` in table & append rows

```js
var html1 = '<tr id="1"><td>aaa</td><td>aaa</td></tr>'; // This position is fine
var html2 = '<tr id="3"><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td></tr>'; // This one is having id '3', it should go to 3rd position. when 2nd comes.
var html3 = '<tr id="2"><td>ccc</td><td>ccc</td></tr>'; // This should go to 2nd position.

$('#myTable tbody').append(html1);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html2);
$('#myTable tbody').append(html3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr><td></td></tr><tr>
            <th>Name</span></th>
            <th>Description</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You missed the important part of the question; the `ccc` row should be *second*